# Redirect to login page with message not working in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When registering for external link, I want to dislay a message :

```
 if (!Auth::check()){
        Session::flash('message', trans('msg.please_create_account_before_playing', ['tournament' => $tournament->name]));
        return redirect(URL::action('Auth\LoginController@login'));
    }
```

In my login page, I have:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
   <div class="alert alert-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    {{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

I checked in my login page, with laravel debugbar, and there is no message var in session.
But it never shows up...

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Cab you Show your routes file?

Comment: It s big... Any part you want to see in special?

Comment: My main focus is on middleware. Which middleware you are using for this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dd(Session::has('message'));` within the login method on your LoginController. I suspect this will return true, if so assign it to a variable of message then pass that variable to the view.

Along the lines of:

```
public function login() {
    $message = Session::has('message') ? Session::get('message') : '';

    return view('login', compact('message'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@if (!empty($message))
    <div class="alert alert-info">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    {{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

If the above does not work, I suspect this may be related to middleware.

Comment: I had 2 copies of the same route in my web.php. So I was moving 1 outside of auth group, but the one being in Auth Group was redirecting to login without the message... my bad!